# microsoft band ioexception in Mscorlib.dll

Tags: windows-phone-8, microsoft-band

I am developing an application for windows phone and microsoft band, the application consists of several pages.

I pass parameters between pages, but the page you are methods of microsoft band and libraries, when I try to run it more than once, gives me the following problem

> 'microsoft.band IOException in Mbcorlib.dll'

and do not know why.

I think it is because it runs more than once, as I call it from the main and other pages, not to mention giving me

> global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application can have only a single, valid `IBandClient` instance (i.e. connection to the Band) at any given time.  If you have multiple pages that each connect to the Band, and you navigate between them without first closing/disposing of the connection before the navigation, then you can expect to see Band communication errors.

Without more specific information about what those pages are doing (e.g. how they're using the Band), it is difficult to guess at the problem you are having.

Comment: i understand, i have three pages with textbox, to set a minimum and maximum value of some parameters of the band, like heart rate, skin temp, and anothers, i need to send a sms if this values are plus or minus of this set values, its all

Comment: how i can fix it? i need a solution please

Comment: Can you provide an excerpt of your code? There's no way a cause for your problems can be determined just from your explanation.

Comment: how i can do that?